# Why in .Net HashHelpers.IsPrime is implemented in this way?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, primes

Looking at .NET `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<T,T>` implementation I found a method [HashHelpers.IsPrime(n)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs,964b5528f9dcae0f,references) which check if number is prime or not. 
I was confused a little bit why they use very simple optimization technique testing only odd numbers starting from 3.

(from source code)

```
int limit = (int)Math.Sqrt (candidate);
for (int divisor = 3; divisor <= limit; divisor+=2)
{
     if ((candidate % divisor) == 0)
          return false;
     }
return true;
```

So, they reduce checks in twice from 3 to limit. But more optimal is testing for numbers 6*k-1,6*k+1 according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) reducing tests in 3 times. And I think there's even more optimal and faster solutions for primality test.

I understand that in particular `Dictionary<T,T>` implementation it's not so important because it is called only for huge dictionaries and in pretty rare cases while resizing. But in general, it's a framework and very popular from well known company. Maybe some logic exists or I don't see something here? Thanks.

Comment: Good point. Now .Net is Open Source and can accept contributions, including optimizations.

Comment: It's not always obvious which algorithm is "optimal" for the average use case. It's worth noting that the [best, Gödel-prize winning algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923063/prime-number-generation-speed-comparison) (according to [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197374/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-the-algorithm-to-check-if-a-number-is-prime), anyway) is [not currently of any practical use](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23260/when-is-the-aks-primality-test-actually-faster-than-other-tests/23360).

Answer (score 17):

> I think there's even more optimal and faster solutions for primality test.

Yep.

> Maybe some logic exists or I don't see something here?

Nope.  You've accurately summed up the situation.

You ask:

> Why in .Net HashHelpers.IsPrime is implemented in a non-optimal way?

and then you answer your own question:

> I understand that in particular `Dictionary<T,T>` implementation it's not so important because it is called only for huge dictionaries and in pretty rare cases while resizing.

So you know the answer to your question. **It's not optimized because fast enough is by definition fast enough**, and the given algorithm is fast enough.

If you want to make it faster, hey, it's open source. Go implement an algorithm you like better and **submit the detailed results of your carefully designed, accurate and precise empirical performance tests** that clearly demonstrate that **making an unnecessary change to a widely used foundational piece of functionality** is justified by your superior performance algorithm in an unimportant and rare scenario.

If that sounds like a lot of work for almost no benefit then again, you know the answer to your question.  Expensive work that has small benefits gets sorted to the bottom of the priority list.

Comment: Looks like the primes are precomputed, in fact, and thus the use of that function was one-time work. Not sure why it's public though.

Comment: I read "fast enough is by definition fast enough" and didn't have to scroll down any more to know it is an Eric Lippert post. One of my favourite phrases of yours! :)

Comment: @AndersonPimentel: Hah, that's funny. No, I did not, but I have written hash tables before, sometimes with *disastrous* consequences.  I once caused a bug in a hash table that brought microsoft.com down to a crawl, but that was back in the 1990s before the web was such a big thing.

Comment: @WillNess: Since that code has probably been in the product twenty years or so, I cannot agree with your assessment. If anyone cared, it would have been changed long ago.  Or perhaps we just haven't waited for the bite in the rear long enough; how many more decades do you estimate it will take?

Comment: @WillNess: I'm not following your train of thought here. You seem to be saying that *because someone in the past might have waited a couple extra minutes for this code to run*, that we should change it *now*.  Why does that hypothetical person's chance to go get a soda from the fridge in 2005 matter in 2018? Again, if it's important to you, hey, it's open source. Go change it and submit a detailed analysis of why this change should be accepted if you feel strongly about it.

Comment: oops, my bad, scratch all I've said. missed  crucial detail in the code, it is already doing what I wanted it to do. sorry for wasting your time.